# How to get hardware accelerated Canvas in onDraw() of CanvasWatchFaceService?

Tags: android, canvas, wear-os

I am developing a Watch Face for android wear. I want to make the Canvas hardware accelerated.

In manifest I declared it like bellow

```
     <application
         android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
         ..>
            <service
            android:name=".WatchFaceMain"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            ..>
    </application>
```

But when I checked it from inside of My onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) method canvas.isHardwareAccelerated() returns false. which clearly means my canvas is not hardware accelerated.

```
 @Override
 public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
       ...
       boolean isAccelarated = canvas.isHardwareAccelerated();
       .......
 }
```

How do I make this canvas Hardware Accelerated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a solution for this issue. Though it wasn't a straight forward or easy solution.

First I got to copy the whole android.support.wearable.watchface.CanvasWatchFaceService class from librar,  which my WatchFaceMain class extended.

Then I had to edit the draw() Method inside Engine Class like bellow

```
public abstract class CanvasWatchFaceService extends WatchFaceService {
    .....

        public class Engine extends android.support.wearable.watchface.WatchFaceService.Engine {
          ...
            private void draw(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                this.mDrawRequested = false;
                Canvas canvas = holder.getSurface().lockHardwareCanvas();
                if(canvas != null) {
                    try {
                        this.onDraw(canvas, holder.getSurfaceFrame());
                    } finally {
                        holder.getSurface().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I edited two lines inside onDraw like bellow.

```
from
 Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
To
 Canvas canvas = holder.getSurface().lockHardwareCanvas();

And From
 holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
To
 holder.getSurface().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

I still wonder why did CanvasWatchFaceService didn't offer any easier way to request for a hardware accelerated canvas!

[More detail solution is available here in this Article.](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hardware-acceleration-android-watch-face-development-shekh-shagar?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_profile_view_base%3BreN4Qe%2F3THOYcrQQClDgfQ%3D%3D)

Hopefully this answer helps someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of the SDK, it's much easier. The `CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine` class has a `boolean useHardwareCanvas` constructor parameter. In your subclass, call the constructor as needed:

```
public Engine() {
    super(true);
}
```

Comment: CanvasWatchFaceService is deprecated, so probably better to use the new APIs.

Comment: True, though when I created a new Watch Face app using Android Studio's template a couple weeks ago, it used `CanvasWatchFaceService`.

Comment: Those Android Studio templates are baked into the IDE, so don't get updated on a different cycle when libraries change.

Answer (score 0):

With the new APIs https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/wear/watchface/WatchFaceService, use CanvasType.HARDWARE

```
    override suspend fun createWatchFace(
        surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder,
        watchState: WatchState,
        complicationSlotsManager: ComplicationSlotsManager,
        currentUserStyleRepository: CurrentUserStyleRepository
    ) = WatchFace(
        WatchFaceType.ANALOG,
        object : Renderer.CanvasRenderer2<MySharedAssets>(
            surfaceHolder,
            currentUserStyleRepository,
            watchState,
            CanvasType.HARDWARE,
            interactiveDrawModeUpdateDelayMillis = 16,
            clearWithBackgroundTintBeforeRenderingHighlightLayer = true
        ) {
```